# T-SQL: putting results of stored procedure into a temp table when you have a timestamp column and can't hardcode column names

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, stored-procedures, timestamp

For my SQL Server unit tests, I am trying to suppress returning all rows when counting results of a "get all rows" stored procedures. To this end I am trying to write the results to a temp table.

I begin with a linked server entry pointing to the current server and database.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE NAME = 'DB_LOCAL')
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT DB_NAME())
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'DB_LOCAL',  @srvproduct = '', @provider = 'SQLOLEDB', @datasrc = @@servername, @catalog=@DBNAME
END
```

This is so that I can use `OPENQUERY` to create a temp table with the output structure of the stored procedure on the fly without having to hard code the columns.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ut_results') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #ut_results

SELECT * 
INTO #ut_results
FROM OPENQUERY (DB_LOCAL, 'EXEC p_AnzLookup_get @id = 0')
```

I want to use this temp table to exec my stored procs into, I can't use `OPENQUERY` again because I need to specify variables as part of the test. Also, the unit test is in a transaction and doing so creates locking issues. Once I have the structure I do this. I can't specify the column names without the timestamp column which I appreciate would work as they could be changed by 3rd parties.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #ut_results

INSERT INTO #ut_results 
    EXEC p_AnzLookup_get @id = @record_id
```

This insert into is failing because I have a timestamp column returned by the stored procedure.

> Msg 273, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

I can't change the timestamp column in the temp table due to this error.

```
ALTER TABLE #ut_results 
   ALTER COLUMN TStamp BINARY(8)
```

> Msg 4928, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Cannot alter column 'TStamp' because it is 'timestamp'.

I can't drop and recreate the timestamp column in the temp table because it changes the column order.

```
ALTER TABLE #ut_results DROP COLUMN TStamp 
ALTER TABLE #ut_results ADD TStamp BINARY(8)
```

Which leads to different errors when data inserts into the wrong columns:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure p_AnzLookup_get, Line 20
>   Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I can't make changes to stored procs these unit tests are for and I can't hard code the column names. I need to write this in a way that is both resilient an reactive to changes outside of my control.

This is just a small subset of one of the unit tests that I have extracted to demonstrate this problem. Any thoughts as to how I get round this sticky bit?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something that will work. Create temp table using OPENQUERY then mash that through XML to get a csv list of column names into a varchar. Then do a replace on this to cast the timestamp column as varbinary(8).

Using the column list from the above I can select the structure of my first temp table into the second with the fields in the correct order and the timestamp column defined as varbinary(8) that can accept timestamp data.

It isnt pretty tho:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ut_results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ut_results
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ut_results2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ut_results2

SELECT * INTO #ut_results2
FROM OPENQUERY ( DB_LOCAL ,'EXEC p_AnzLookup_get @id=-1' )


DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @cols = Stuff(( select ',' + name from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id =
                       object_id('tempdb..#ut_results2')
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE                       
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                     , 1, 1, '')
SET @cols = REPLACE(@cols,'TStamp','CAST(TStamp AS VARBINARY(8)) AS TStamp')

DECLARE @SQl VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' INTO #ut_results FROM #ut_results2 WHERE 1=2'
EXEC (@SQl)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ut_results2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ut_results2
```

EDIT:
One slight change to this. In the above I create the final temp table in dynamic SQL but it was not accessible afterwards. I have changed this to a regular table.

```
DECLARE @SQl VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' INTO ut_results FROM #ut_results2'
EXECUTE (@SQl)
```